# how push data to array with async nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a problem in nodejs. I want to push data from my sequelize query to array. this is my code

```
exports.getdoctorcategorybyid = async (req, res) => {
    var id = req.params.id;
    doctorcategory.findOne({
        where: {
            dokter_category_id: id
        }
    })
    .then((doctorcategoryes) => {
        if (doctorcategoryes) {
            var l = [];
            var dokter_l = doctorcategoryes.id_doctor.split(', ');
            for(var b = 0; b < dokter_l.length; b++){
                Dokterl.findOne({
                    where: {
                        id_doctor: dokter_l[b]
                    }
                }).then((dokterl) => {
                    l.push(dokterl);
                })
            }
            // data []
            console.log(l)
            res.status(200).json({
                error: false,
                response: "List!",
                data: doctorcategoryes,
            });
        }else{
            res.status(200).json({
                error: true,
                response: "not found!",
                data: [],
            });
        }
    })
};
```

i want to show data from variable `l` but result from variable l is `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exports.getdoctorcategorybyid = async (req, res) => {
var id = req.params.id;
doctorcategory.findOne({
    where: {
        dokter_category_id: id
    }
})
.then(async(doctorcategoryes) => {
    if (doctorcategoryes) {
        var dokter_l = doctorcategoryes.id_doctor.split(', ');
       var l= await Promise.all(dokter_l.map(async (item) => {
         return await Dokterl.findOne({
                where: {
                    id_doctor: item
                }
            });

           }));
        console.log(l)
        res.status(200).json({
            error: false,
            response: "List!",
            data: doctorcategoryes,
        });

    }else{
        res.status(200).json({
            error: true,
            response: "not found!",
            data: [],
        });
    }
}) };
```

You can try like this with Promise.all.

Comment: thank you very much sir, you solve my problem